# Sort a list of lists containing integers

Tags: python

I've got a list of lists containing integers sorted at the moment by the sum of the contents:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 0], [1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0], [4, 0, 0]]
```

I would like to sort them in ascending order by the common structure of its contents i.e like

```
[[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0,0,3], [0,0,4]... ]
```

I have seen the docs but I can't figure out how I can do this.

Comment: Is this a  computer generated list? Because you have errors in it.

Comment: the correct list is [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 0], [1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0], [4, 0, 0]]

Comment: Can you explain the intent of your sort? I'm not sure what "common structure" means such that [1,0,0] would sort before [0,1,0], for example.

Comment: Try to describe in one sentence how you would compare two items

Comment: Is not the result: [[1, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 0],
 [4, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0],
 [2, 1, 0],
 [3, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 0],
 [2, 2, 0],
 [0, 3, 0],
 [1, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 0],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [3, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [2, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [0, 3, 1],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 2],
 [2, 0, 2],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 4]]

Comment: I mean by the common presence of items in the sub index of each list. I am thinking of something like if list.count('0')==2 but I am not sure.

Comment: @Eastsun No I would like to achieve the result stated in my question

Comment: @user1987097 Can you include the full expected result, otherwise the question is too ambiguous to give an answer.

Comment: @Aya It is only the part in the question that is important the next entries can proceed however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're after...

```
>>> l = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 0], [1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0], [4, 0, 0]]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: (-x.count(0), x[::-1]))
>>> l
[[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 4], [1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 3], [0, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: @Aya , Giving a solution without having the requirements are hallmarks of a great software engineer. You are going a long way :P

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html for an explanation of the Python sort capability, including a discussion of "Key Functions" which gives you whatever additional flexibility you need beyond the basic sort.

Answer (score 1):

Use your sorting criteria function as `key` in the sorting.

```
input_list = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 0], [1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0], [4, 0, 0]]

sorted_list = sorted(input_list,key=my_sorting_func)
```

Comment: Ah yes I have seen this but I am not sure how to write the `key,` I was thinking something like input_list[::1] but I am entirely unsure

Comment: If you treated "0" as sorting after the positive integers, would that accomplish what you're looking for?